# Append multiple options in html select at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append multiple options in *html select*.

Currently I'm using the below code in a loop, but it make the working slow as it have to add new option every time.

**Code Snippet:**

```
s.options[s.options.length]= new Option(url, '1');
```

So I guess, if I can add all the options at once and not one by one like above, maybe it can make it little faster.

Please suggest a more fast function then this one. Thanks

Comment: http://www.creativecg.com/addremove-options-from-a-select-box-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

> s.options[s.options.length]=function Option(url,'1') {
>      // statements go here
>   };

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it with a `DocumentFragment` but I'm unsure about browser support. It certainly works in current versions of all browsers (including IE 10) but I doubt it works in old IE.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "" + i;
    option.text = "Option " + i;
    frag.appendChild(option);
}

s.appendChild(frag);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QsNpe/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tmpOptions = [];
for(var i=0; i<optionsLength; i++) {
    tmpOptions[i] = new Option(url, i);
}
s.options = tmpOptions;
```

Comment: It is not displaying any thing in the options...plz check in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var dataArr = [{'value':'val1','text':'text1'},
               {'value':'val2','text':'text2'},
               {'value':'val3','text':'text3'},
               {'value':'val4','text':'text4'},
               {'value':'val5','text':'text5'},
               {'value':'val6','text':'text6'},
               {'value':'val7','text':'text7'}];

// Removes all options for the select box
$('#optExample option').remove();

// .each loops through the array
$.each(dataArr, function(i){
    $('#optExample').append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",dataArr[i]['value'])
                    .text(dataArr[i]['text']));
});
```